# SQLAlchemy query where a column contains quotation marks

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Searching for a string that contains quotation marks...

My environment is as follow:

MySql database with a table that has a column from type `mediumtext`  which contains a dictionary (for example: `{ "a": "a1", "b": "b1" }`) - it is an existing system, so I can't change its type to `json`.

Using SQLAlchemy (python), I'm trying to query for rows that contains certain key & value (for example: `"a": "a1"`).
tried different variations such as (and many more):

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.contains('"a": "a1"'))
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.contains("'a': 'a1'"))
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.contains('\"a\": \"a1\"'))
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.like('%"a": "a1"%'))
```

but couldn't find the right formatting that will return the expected results   :(

any ideas?

Comment: `contains('"a": "a1"')` should work. Are you sure the whitespace in the value is as you showed?

Comment: If it doesn't, it would be useful to see the raw query and data

Comment: there should not be spaces 
I'll look into it, and run some more tests around it...

Comment: my problem is the ", even if I'm searching only for " or ' it doesn't return any results.
for example: 
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.like('%"%')) 
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.MyColumn.contains("%'%"))
etc.